# Find prime factors of sum of non-composite Fibonacci numbers up to n

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, fibonacci

**The Challenge**

Given a number, find the sum of the non-composite numbers in the Fibonacci sequence up to that number, and find the prime factors of the sum.

For example, if you were given 8, the non-composite numbers would be 1, 1, 2, 3, and 5. Adding these up would get 12. The prime factors of 12 are 2, 2 and 3, so your program should return something along the lines of `2, 2, 3` when given 12.

**The Objective**

This is Code Golf, so the answer with the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: The title reads like something out of a PPCG Markov chain generator. Primes and Fibonacci numbers have been way overdone (see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/20260) about primes). This isn't something I'd expect a new user to necessarily know, so a heads up for potential downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 8 bytes

```
fΣ}
```

Doesn't work on TIO, but works locally.

Explanation:

```
            Inclusive range [1 .. input]
 f           Fibonacci numbers
           Get elements that are only in both lists
   Σ         Keep each element where running the following is falsy
              Check if composite
     }       Close loop
             Sum
            Prime factors
```